# 401 Authorization Required on Twitter API request

Tags: python, twitter, request, signature, http-status-code-401

I'm building an Python script to automatically post status updates on Twitter. I've carefully read and followed the API documentation for creating a signature and do the request to update the status. But I'm getting an error when doing the request.

```
HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
```

I've seen more questions like this on Stackoverflow and other resources, but couldn't find a solution to this problem yet.

```
 def sendTweet(self):

      url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'
      message = 'Testing'

      oauths = [
            ['oauth_consumer_key', '1234567890'],
            ['oauth_nonce', self.generate_nonce()],
            ['oauth_signature', ''],
            ['oauth_signature_method', 'HMAC-SHA1'],
            ['oauth_timestamp', str(int(time.time()))],
            ['oauth_token', '1234567890'],
            ['oauth_version', '1.0']
        ]

        signature = self.sign(oauths, message)
        oauths[2][1] = signature

        count = 0
        auth = 'OAuth '
        for oauth in oauths:
            count = count + 1
            if oauth[1]:
                auth = auth + self.quote(oauth[0]) + '="' + self.quote(oauth[1]) + '"'
            if count < len(oauths):
                auth = auth + ', '

        headers = {
            'Authorization': auth,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }

        payload = {'status' : message.encode('utf-8')}

        req = urllib2.Request(url, data=urllib.urlencode(payload), headers=headers)

        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            data = response.read()
            print data
        except (urllib2.HTTPError, urllib2.URLError) as err:
            print err
```

This is what the `self.sign` function does

```
def sign(self, oauths, message):

        signatureParams = ''
        count = 0

        values = [
            ['oauth_consumer_key', oauths[0][1]],
            ['oauth_nonce', oauths[1][1]],
            ['oauth_signature_method', oauths[3][1]],
            ['oauth_timestamp', oauths[4][1]],
            ['oauth_token', oauths[5][1]],
            ['oauth_version', oauths[6][1]],
            ['status', message]
        ]

        customerSecret = '1234567890'
        tokenSecret = '1234567890'

        for value in oauths:
            count = count + 1
            signatureParams = signatureParams + self.quote(value[0]) + '=' + self.quote(value[1])
            if count < len(oauths):
                signatureParams = signatureParams + '&'

        signature = 'POST&' + self.quote(self.endPoint) + '&' + self.quote(signatureParams)
        signinKey = self.quote(customerSecret) + '&' + self.quote(tokenSecret)

        signed = base64.b64encode(self.signRequest(signinKey, signature))

        return signed
```

And below are the helper functions.

```
def generate_nonce(self):
    return ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(8)])

def quote(self, param):
    return urllib.quote(param.encode('utf8'), safe='')

def signRequest(self, key, raw):
    from hashlib import sha1
    import hmac
    hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, sha1)
    return hashed.digest().encode('base64').rstrip('\n')
```

This is what the auth string looks like when I print it.

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="1234567890",
oauth_nonce="78261149",
oauth_signature="akc2alpFWWdjbElZV2RCMmpGcDc0V1d1S1B3PQ%3D%3D",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1540896473",
oauth_token="1234567890",
oauth_version="1.0"
```

That is exactly like it should be if I read the Twitter documentation. But still I get the 401 Authorization Required error.. I just can't see what is going wrong here.

The Access level for the keys is `Read, write, and direct messages`

All keys are replaced with `1234567890`, but in the actual code I use the real ones.

Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!